# Filter elements in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I should only take some items.
Take groups that do not contain Z4TC in the Model tag

The excel file schema is as follows

```
<ConfigRegolatori>
<Id>6</Id>
<Address>92</Address>
<Category>90</Category>
<Mode>TC_K</Mode>
<Model>Z4TC</Model>
<Name>KT6</Name>
<Port>COM1</Port>
<Channel>2</Channel>
<LowerEndScale>0</LowerEndScale>
<UpperEndScale>400</UpperEndScale>
<NegativeGradient>10</NegativeGradient>
<PositiveGradient>10</PositiveGradient>
<PercX10>false</PercX10>
```

```
<ConfigRegolatori>
<Id>7</Id>
<Address>7</Address>
<Category>100</Category>
<Mode>TC_K</Mode>
<Model>M9_Servo</Model>
<Name>KT7</Name>
<Port>COM1</Port>
<Channel />
<LowerEndScale>0</LowerEndScale>
<UpperEndScale>400</UpperEndScale>
<NegativeGradient>10</NegativeGradient>
<PositiveGradient>10</PositiveGradient>
<PercX10>false</PercX10>
```

The code part is the following

```
dtConfReg = new DataTable();
                dtConfReg.ReadXml(Principale.strPathConfig + "\\ConfigRegulators.xml");
                dtConfReg.TableName = "ConfigReg";

bsouReg = new BindingSource();
                bsouReg.DataSource = dtConfReg;
                dgvwConfigReg.DataSource = bsouReg;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`Filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the BindingSource:

```
bsouReg = new BindingSource();
bsouReg.DataSource = dtConfReg;
bsouReg.Filter = "Model <> 'Z4TC'";
dgvwConfigReg.DataSource = bsouReg;
```

The documentation for the filter expression can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hello I am always myself.
Since I have multiple rows with the same value in the Address field, I would like to get a row for each value.
For example, I have multiple records with the Address tag at 92, I just want to extract one.